# All groups of order 12; Dic12 and D6

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, sylow-theory, dihedral-groups

I know this has been asked in various forms before, but so far I have failed to understand those answers properly. I've also read several papers discussing this, but I don't really get it.

I have an assignment in my algebraic structures class to find all groups of order 12. I know that there are 5; $Z_{12}, Z_2\times Z_2\times Z_3, A_4, D_6, Dic_{12}$. I have found the first three and shown that they are not isomorphic. So that leaves me $D_6\cong Z_2\times S_3$ (or $D_{12}$), the symmetries of a regular hexagon, and $Dic_{12}$, which I'm not familiar with.

Using Sylow's theorem I have that these two have 1 3-sylow subgroup and 3 2-sylow subgroups. The 3-sylow subgroup $P_3\cong Z_3$. The 2-sylow subgroups are either isomorphic to $Z_4$ or $Z_2\times Z_2$.

Case 1:
$P_3\cong Z_3$ and 2-sylow subgroups $\cong Z_4$ should give me $Dic_{12}=\{a,x|a^6=e, x^2=a^3, xax^{-1}=a^{-1}\}$ but I don't know how to show this.

Case 2:
$P_3\cong Z_3$ and 2-sylow subgroups $\cong Z_2\times Z_2$ should give me $D_6=\{a,x|a^6=x^2=e, xax=a^{-1}\}$ but I don't know how to show this either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For Case 1, you have $P_3=\langle y \rangle$ with $|y|=3$ and $P_2 = \langle x \rangle$ with $|x|=4$.

Since $P_3 \lhd G$, we have $xyx^{-1} \in P$, so it must equal $y$ or $y^{-1}$. But we are assuming that $G$ is nonabelian, so $xyx^{-1}=y^{-1}$.

Hence $x^2yx^{-2}=xy^{-1}x^{-1} = y$, so $x^2$ (which has order $2$) commutes with $y$, and hence $a:=x^2y$ has order $6$.

Now $a^3=x^6y^3=x^2$ and $xax^{-1}=x(x^2y)x^{-1}=x^2y^{-1}=a^{-1}$. So $G$ is isomorphic to the group $\langle a,x \mid a^6=1,x^2=a^3,xax^{-1}=a^{-1}\rangle$, which is your definition of ${\rm Dic}_{12}$.

Maybe you could have another go at Case 2 yourself.

Comment: Thank you! I understand this, but I'm not getting anywhere with case 2. I know that $P_3=\langle y\rangle$, $y^3=e$ and $P_2=\{e,x_1,x_2,x_3\}$, $x_i^2=e$. $P_3\vartriangleleft G$ so $xyx^{-1}\in P_3$ and G non-abelian so $xyx^{-1}=xyx=y^{-1}$. Then I have $y=xy^{-1}x$. And now I'm lost. How can I find $a$?

Comment: If,say $x_1yx_1=y^{-1}$ and $x_2yx_2=y^{-1}$, then $x_3yx_3=y$. So in any case one of $x_1,x_2,x_3$ - say $x_3$ must satisfiy $x_3yx_3=y$. Now $a:=x_3y$ has order $6$.

Comment: $xax=x(xy)x=yx$ and $a^{-1}=y^{-1}x$. But if they are the same then $y=y^{-1}$ which is not true?

Comment: Put $x=x_1$ and $a=x_3y$. Then $xax=x_3y^{-1}=a^{-1}$.

Answer (score 0):

in cas 2, is by definition of the group $D_6$. The second $Disc_{12}$ is a group not abelian and deferent to $D_6 $ and $A_4$,  the deferent  between the structure of $Disc_{12}$ and $D_6$ that the group $Disc_{12}$
contain an element $x$  of order $4$, and the second group $D_6$ no contain element fo order  $4$, of course this two groups are derent to $A_4$ (this is a classification of  non abelian groupes of order 12).

Comment: Yes, I know that. But I want to derive $D_6$ and $Dic_{12}$ from their subgroups.

Comment: as you said, the 2_sylow of $ D_6$ is $\Bbb{Z} /
2\Bbb{Z}\times\Bbb{Z} / 2\Bbb{Z}$, while the 2-Sylow  of
$Disc_{12}$ is $\Bbb{Z} / 4\Bbb{Z}$ So they are different and they
are characterized by have  order 12, not abelian and do not
contains subgroups of order 6.

Maybe I misunderstood the question.

Comment: Sorry,i fix a typo in my above comment: D_6 and D_12 are characterized
by the order 12, non  abelian  and containing a subgroup of order
6.